# patterns in python-complex

Tags: python-2.7

Can we use the fact that `11*11=121,111*111=12321` and so on..?
I tried this-
N=input("enter number of rows"

Comment: You can do in a lot of ways, but you need to show some code(effort) so we can help you.

Comment: I would say don't speculate just do it.

Comment: Yes, you can use that relationship to get the value for each line, then you just need to figure out how to get the appropriate formatting.

Comment: @jonrsharpe how do we write that code

Comment: This isn't a code-writing service. Python has [a tutorial](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/index.html), I suggest you start there.

Comment: Thats really helpful! At least tell me what next or what is wrong in my code!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the following code:

```
def upanddown(n):
    return range(1, n) + range(n, 0, -1)

def triangle(rows):
    for num in xrange(1, rows + 1):
        print ' '.join(map(str, upanddown(num))).center(rows * 4 - 3)

rows = input("Number of rows: ")
triangle(rows)
```

*Output*:

```
Number of rows: 4
      1      
    1 2 1    
  1 2 3 2 1  
1 2 3 4 3 2 1
```

Comment: I provided the code, try at least to understand how to use it.. you have to invoke `triangle(4)`

Comment: @user166748 you don't need the columns, just invoke `triangle(rows)`

Comment: @user166748 I mean that you should learn how to walk before trying to run. Check the edit ;)

Comment: @user166748 When you use `def something(arguments):` you are defining a function, in order to execute the code inside that you have to *invoke* the function passing some argument. That's done using the function name followed by parentheses wrapping the arguments. So `triangle(rows)` means that you want to execute the code inside `triangle` using `rows` as argument. In your case `rows` is `4`, so inside the function the variable `rows` will be `4`. Try to check these [resources](https://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide)

Comment: ahh...understood. will surely go through the resources also